# Transfering objects from list into array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort, singly-linked-list

Background info: kragarm is a singly-linked list made up of two sorts of loads (single force and a moment which both implement the Interface IBelastung). I'm trying to copy the objects into a 1d array (objekte), sort it out according to their position, and put its attributes (position, force, and moment) in a 2d array (verlauf). The Method bildeAufDouble() gets you the position of the load
This is my code:

```
public double[][] stelleVerlaufDar() {

    IBelastung[] objekte = new IBelastung[kragarm.anzahlElemente()];

    double[][] verlauf = new double[kragarm.anzahlElemente()][3];

    IMeinIterator it = kragarm.iterator();      
    while (it.hatNaechsten()) {         
        IBelastung aktueller = (IBelastung) it.naechsten();

        for (int i = 0; i < objekte.length; i++) {
            objekte[i] = aktueller;     
            System.out.print("| " + String.format("%6.2f",objekte[i].bildeAbAufDouble())+" |");
            System.out.println();
            }
        }

    SortierenEinesFeldes.bubbleSort(objekte);
    System.out.println("Sortierten Laengen");

    for (int i = 0; i < objekte.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("| " + String.format("%6.2f",objekte[i].bildeAbAufDouble())+" |");
    }
    System.out.println();
```

And this is my console
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqjng.png)

Why does it print the numbers 5 times, and then after it's supposed to be sorted, why does it print the sorted only the first number and 5 times? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < objekte.length; i++) {
    objekte[i] = aktueller;     
}
```

This fills the whole array with the same element: `aktueller`.

You shouldn't have two nested loops. You should have just one, and it should increment `i` at each iteration:

```
int i = 0;
while (it.hatNaechsten()) {         
    IBelastung aktueller = (IBelastung) it.naechsten();
    objekte[i] = aktueller;   
    i++;
}
```

Also, note that you're not storing anything into the `verlauf`array returned by the method.

Comment: THANKI YOU SO MUCH! Yes, that's the next step- to fill out verlauf.